# How to determine what profiles are part of an LXD container or archive when copying or importing

Tags: lxc, lxd

I get the following error when trying to import an LXD container from a backup.tar.gz archive:

`$: sudo lxc import backup.tar.gz`

***Error: Failed importing backup: Failed loading profiles for instance: Profile not found***

This error provides no information regarding what specific profile/s aren't available on the system, so it's not clear how to recreate them.

**Is there a way to determine what profiles are part of a container or exported backup.tar.gz file?**

---

Fortunately, I have an old container (but different version) of the backup.tar.gz file.  I attempted to determine what profiles were attached using:

`$: sudo lxc <container> info`

This only provides snapshot and active instance details, but nothing about profiles. As a work around, I was able to publish the container on another server as an image.

`$: sudo lxc publish local:<container>  host2:  --alias <container>`

The resulting image doesn't have any attached profiles.  Now I can recreate containers from this image without error, but this isn't ideal, and only possible because I was fortunate in having a working container available.

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer to part of my question.

`$: sudo lxc config show <container>`

Does show what profiles are attached to my working container.  However, this doesn't help in the case of importing from an archive.